# How to use variables for styles in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have following scenario:

function 1:

```
myFunction(obj){
  //returns HTML code as string
}
```

Example:

```html
<div>
   <div style="color: black; margin-bottom: 10px;">
      <h3 style="font-size: 15px;  display:inline;">Pipeline :  </h3>
      <h3 style="font-size: 20px; display:inline;"> '+obj.name+' </h3>
      <div id="status" style="display:inline; font-size:10px;"></div>
   </div>
   <div style="margin-bottom: 10px;">
      <h3 style="font-size: 15px;  display:inline;">Status message :  </h3>
      <h3 style="font-size: 20px; display:inline;"> '+obj.statusMessage+' </h3>
   </div>
 </div>
```

function 2:
calls function 1 by passing the object;

```
callmyFunction(){
  obj={
    "name": "abc",
    "statusMessage" : "fdsffs"
    ...
  }
  var str = myFunction(obj);
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=str;
}
```

My html has a div with id = "demo"

```
<div id="demo"></div>
```

Now i want to dynamically change the color of a div with id = "status" from myFuncton() which is part of the HTML string returned. Something like this: (But this throws error 'Cannot read property 'style' of null
    at myFunction (:17:34)')

```
document.getElementById("status").style.color=variable;
```

Here variable is decided based on the obj properties dynamically (obj is passed as parameter)

If there is a way to bind variables to style property in the string returned then the problem would be solved

like:

```
 <div id="status" style="display:inline; font-size:10px; color=
 {{variable}}"></div>
```

I cannot use CSS classes because it is for emails. And i know i can use CSS for any other case.

And the above code is pseudo code. Dont look for syntac errors.

Comment: If you only want to give color to `#status` (you have a proper selector), why don't you use css instead?

Comment: It is not recommended to use CSS classes for emails. Everything must be inline CSS

Comment: You should have mentioned this in Question.

Comment: Sorry i missed it :( and someone downvoted the question as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add your JavaScript inside the `<body>`area. When you run the function, the DOM is not finding any element with id `status` and returning as `null`. If you move your scripts inside the body content it will work. Look at the following fiddle.

[Wrap JavaScript inside BODY](https://jsfiddle.net/6tpa0szx/)

In the above fiddle, I have chosen the JavaScript Load Type as `No wrap - in <body>` and i can able to see the colour changes. If I change the Load Type to `No wrap - in <head>` then I am getting the null error.

Answer (score 1):

The error you got (*Cannot read property 'style' of null*) means your code `document.getElementById("status")` is returning `null`. In other words, the *div* with the *id* `status` does not exist in the DOM at the time you call your function `myFunction()`.

`document.getElementById()` looks for elements in the DOM, not in a random Javascript variable you would call `str`. If it is not in the DOM - in your html document - the function will not find it.

Answer (score 0):

Why not using CSS classes? That is what they are for. You define your styles in your stylesheets. And then you add the relevant classes using javascipt (`document.getElementById("status").classList.add("js-red-color")`).

I usually prefix my css classes with `js-` so I know they are added dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

You missed **function** keyword before your function name. Please check below code snippet.

```js
function myFunction(obj){
        var  str =  '                                                                  \
          <div>                                                                       \
            <div style="color: black; margin-bottom: 10px;">                          \
            <h3 style="font-size: 15px;  display:inline;">Pipeline :  </h3>           \
            <h3 style="font-size: 20px; display:inline;"> '+obj.name+' </h3>          \
            <div id="status" style="display:inline; font-size:10px;"> red colored div </div>           \
         </div>                                                                       \
         <div style="margin-bottom: 10px;">                                           \
            <h3 style="font-size: 15px;  display:inline;">Status message :  </h3>     \
            <h3 style="font-size: 20px; display:inline;"> '+obj.statusMessage+' </h3> \
         </div>                                                                       \
       </div>' ;
     
       return str;
       }
      
      
      function callmyFunction(){
        obj={
          "name": "abc",
          "statusMessage" : "fdsffs"
        };
      
        var str = myFunction(obj);
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=str;
      }
      
      //calling callmyFunction() on load
      callmyFunction();
   document.getElementById("status").style.color='black';
   alert('Changing color to red');
      document.getElementById("status").style.color='red';
```

```html
<html>
   <head>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div id="demo"></div>
   </body>
   <!-- script tag goes here -->
</html>
```

Comment: The code in the question was pseudo code. I am seeking a way to add variables to inline styles.

Comment: you have skipped just function keyword to change your code into pseudo code :D

Comment: Can you please write your exact code so that we can know where you are facing the issue.